# How to heartbeat X11 screensaver?

Tags: c, unix, x11

X11 has a screensaver mechanism that can be controlled by `xset` command. Without having to invoke the external command to disable or heartbeat the screensaver, from inside my X11 application, how can I heartbeat the screensaver mechanism so to prevent it from shutting down the monitor?

Answer (score 3):

If this on a modern Linux system, the preferred FreeDesktop method is to ping the DBus interface, specifically `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.SimulateUserActivity()` or another part of the exposed interface, depending on your needs.

Comment: There's also a setting on the DBus (I believe) to specifically inhibit the screensaver; e.g. Totem sets this.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that's `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Throttle(string appName, string localizedReason)`, returning a cookie. `UnThrottle(int cookie)` would then be used to reenable the screensaver (it would also resume if the app exits).

Comment: Trying to run `$ qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver` tells me "Service 'org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver' does not exist." It is not that I knew what I was doing, because I am not really into this DBus thing, but it seems that this interface is not available in my system. My system is new, Linux Mint 12 (based on Ubuntu 11.10). What processes should provide these services?

Answer (score 0):

As well as the D-Bus solution suggested by @Kitsune. You can also take the approach that some media players do and simulate the pressing of a key (e.g. Alt) at regular intervals.

This code in totem: http://git.gnome.org/browse/totem/tree/lib/totem-scrsaver.c is designed to be dropped into your code base (it's LGPL v2.1) and will use both the D-Bus interface and also use `XTest` to synthesize pressing the Alt key every 30s.